# "cargo build-bpf" doesn't work on macOs

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli

When I run `cargo build-bpf` I got an error:

> Failed to execute /Users/xh/.cache/solana/v1.37/platform-tools/rust/bin/rustc: No such file or directory (os error 2)

But I ensure my env is ok. Here is my env.

```
❯ solana --version
solana-cli 1.16.2 (src:02d5647b; feat:2891131721, client:SolanaLabs)

❯ cargo --version
cargo 1.70.0 (ec8a8a0ca 2023-04-25)

❯ rustc --version
rustc 1.72.0-nightly (d9c13cd45 2023-07-05)

❯ rustup --version
rustup 1.26.0 (5af9b9484 2023-04-05)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.72.0-nightly (d9c13cd45 2023- 
07-05)`
```

The notice is can't find dir, but I can't find `solana` dir in my `.cache` folder.

Is that mean my solana install failed? Or rust install failed? Or do I have a wrong version?

This is my PC info:

```
macOS Ventura 13.4.1
cpu Intel Core i7 6 core (macBook Pro 2019 A1990)
```

Comment: When i switch solana-cli version  to 1.14.20 ,I got a new error `package `solana-program v1.16.2` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.68.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.62.0-dev`

Comment: I switch my rustup version to 1.62.0 && 1.68.0 . Doesn’t  work still ...

Answer (score 2):

Tried various solutions, finally downgrading `solana-cli` version to `1.16.1` solved the problem.